# Build debian file from source using bazel

Tags: tensorflow, debian, bazel

How do I build a debian package from source using bazel?

I am trying to build debian packagefor tensorflow. I need that to be included in our PPA server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

building Debian packages consists of compiling the software (mostly; there are also packages that don't need compilation, e.g. for scripting languages), and then packaging the artifacts.

Therefore the packaging process has a separate "build" step, which is used to trigger your software's build process.
This step doesn't care whether you use `make`, `CMake`, `SCons`, `bazel` or whatever, as long as *you* tell it what it should do.

a simplistic `debian/rules` file for your needs could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_build:
    bazel build //main:hello-world
```

But of course there is quite a lot to Debian packaging in general, so you make sure you read (and understand) the [Debian Packaging Documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging) first...